# Keystroke ctrl+Slash sends ctrl+Minus to application in 17.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 17.10, shortcuts

Since the update from 17.04 to 17.10 any keyboard I add to the computer the `ctrl+/` keystroke always ends up as `ctrl+-`. Currently I have a german Keyboard, using the english Keyboard layout.

Any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The keytable for the english language pack didn't install correctly and the fallback for all ctrl+ were the german keys.

I fixed the issue by reinstalling the english language pack.

Comment: How to reinstall the english language pack?